# How to generate UUID using mongodb scripting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, uuid

I plan to write a script to alter mongodb tables and fields based on this source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

I plan to generate a UUID and put in a new field to be added to the altered tables, I found this reference [on how to generate a BSON UUID object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID/)
but there's a need for me to specify **a 32-byte hexadecimal string to convert to the UUID BSON subtype**. Ideally I'm looking for a mongodb equivalent to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) which it auto generates UUID v1 by creating a random hash itself without the need of a 32-byte hexadecimal input. How is this done? I plan to create a script on this which mongodb will execute.

Answer (score 2):

Since I think there's no direct mongodb solution, I used this instead: [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript), there's a fiddle which is fit for my needs.

Comment: How did you include and run NPM module in MongoDB Shell?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use this `bson-objectid` library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-objectid